# Do I need to install the MLX_OFED in dockers to using the mlx5 drivers?

Tags: docker, hyperlink, linux-device-driver, dpdk, mellanox

I have installed the MLX_OFED on my physical servers. Now, I will configure a DPDK based on Mellanox connect-5 NIC on docker, do I need to install MLX_OFED on docker again? Can the DPDK installed on the docker be linked to the MLX5 driver on the physical machine?